# No DevTools existe alguma maneira de captura a tela inteira do site, mesmo que tenha scroll?

Tags: google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, documentação, ui, dev-tools

Não procuro por extensão do Chorme ou código de captura de tela etc. Apenas quero saber se essa ***ferramente do desenvolvedor*** tem alguma opção nativa desse tipo.

Sei que se vc abrir o `DevTools` do Chrome e pressionar <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + C</kbd> e fizer uma seleção na tela vc vai salvar como imagem essa parte da tela que vc fez a seleção. Até ai ok.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que eu quero documentar umas telas e gostaria de saber se pelo `DevTools` tem como eu fazer uma captura *fullscreen* do site, mesmo se ele tiver barra de rolagem. Tipo essas imagens de site inteiro que vemos por ai.

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sabia dessa funcionalidade de capturar uma parte da tela, eu testei aqui e não funcionou aparentemente. Quando pressiono CTRL+SHIFT+C ele apenas leva meu mouse para selecionar os elementos da tela, mas só para direcionar no HTML :(

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel primeiro vc tem que abrir o devtools, aperta f12, e depois usa o atalho de captura que falei

Comment: Você utiliza no Windows? Será que sofre alguma alteração para Linux? Pois inclusive aqui o F12 não abre o devtools, só o CTRL+SHIFT+I

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel mil desculpes jovem, é a partir do Chorme 62, apesar de que no Win já está no Chrome 71, então não é tão novo assim... Aqui tem o link do comunicado oficial da Google https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#screenshots

Comment: Show, agora sim, valeu!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não sei se a solução a seguir se enquadra em:

> Não procuro por extensão do Chorme ou **código de captura de tela** etc

Com o `DevTools` digite  `CTRL + SHIFT + P` e a seguir abrirá o menu de comando

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida, digite `screenshot` e escolha *full size screenshot* e o download é feito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece que é isso mesmo! Legal esse prompt do Chrome!